# Get full path on Sitecore item delete

Tags: .net, events, sitecore

Working with Sitecore 8 Update 2

I've added some configuration and the code to capture the event when an item is deleted. I want to get the full path of the item but all I can get is `[orphan]/{itemName}` ( where `{itemName}` is the `itemName`, but it always contains the literal string `[orphan]` ).

So i assume bassicaly that by the time that I get the event the item has already been deleted and i can no longer get the path? Is there an other way to get the path of an item as it is being deleted?

Configuration:

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <events>
      <event name="item:deleted">
        <handler type="be.absi.kbs.web.Helpers.Processors.SaveItemActions, be.absi.kbs.web" method="OnItemDeleted" patch:before="*[@type='Sitecore.Links.ItemEventHandler, Sitecore.Kernel']" />
      </event>
     </events>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Code:

```cs
public class SaveItemActions : PublishItemProcessor // Multi purpose class, catches saves, publishes, etc..
{
    protected void OnItemDeleted(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        Item item = Event.ExtractParameter(args, 0) as Item;
        if (isValidItem(item))
        {
            ItemActionDAO.Insert(CreateItemAction("Deleted", item), item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `item:deleting` event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are binding to the deleted event which happens AFTER the item has been deleted. You probably want to bind earlier in the event model (such as 'deleting', as suggested by @Marek Musielak) to get the information you need.

Note that it is possible for an item to NOT be deleted between deleting event and deleted as an action listening to the event might cause the delete to fail. For this reason, make sure you are only capturing the data you need and still listen to the deleted event to know when the item has actually been deleted.

Answer (score 5):

Add new handler to `item:deleting` event:

```xml
<events>
  <event name="item:deleting">
    <handler type="My.Assembly.Namespace.ItemEventHandler, My.Assembly" method="OnItemDeleting" />
  </event>
</events>
```

And code:

```cs
public class ItemEventHandler
{
    public void OnItemDeleting(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        if (args != null)
        {
            var item = Event.ExtractParameter(args, 0) as Item;
            Assert.IsNotNull(item, "No item in parameters");
            string path = item.Paths.FullPath;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems i do need this solution. But if i'm not mistaken the delete process can still be aborted after my custom code has run by other handlers ? If so i would also need a way to capture this. 
EDIT: i've combined the 2 as Jay suggested. Saving the id and path in a stati dictionary on the deleting event and fetching it on the deleted event.

Comment: You can also save it to Sitecore.Context.Items, which is only alive for the duration of the request/event pipeline execution.